# Glossiness not appearing in cycles render - working in preview

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

[image: this is in the rendered image using cycles, notice how flat it looks]

[image: this is from the preview, this is the look i want]

Render is not consistent with preview for glossy shader.

All of my scene is visible in the preview and the render. There aren't any objects or lights hidden in either preview or the render.

I have an HDRI for the world shader. This is in the preview as world scene is on

I have tried turning off motion blur

All of the render output settings are the same for the preview and the render

More info: this is a glossy shader mixed with a principled bsdf. The principled has a low alpha to give the shader transparency. The blend mode is set to alpha blend

Please help if you can! I am hoping I just missed a tick box somewhere

Comment: Hello, if Pixelpilot's answer doesn't work, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your scene world is set up the same as your viewport shading. The viewport shows the inbuilt Blender HDRI which is not automatically put into your Scene world.
To get a matching view make sure you tick the scene world in your viewport shading.
[image]